# Prepend string to list item and turn it into JSON in Ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, formatting, jinja2

I have a list of ports

```yaml
ports:
  - 123
  - 456
  - 789
```

that I like to turn into `containerPort` for usage in a Kubernetes deployment:

```
"container_ports": [
            {
                "containerPort": 123
            },
            {
                "containerPort": 456
            },
            {
                "containerPort": 789
            }
        ]
```

The example above is created when I define `ports` as

```yaml
ports:
  - containerPort: 123
  - containerPort: 456
  - containerPort: 789
```

However, I'd like to save the user some typing and add `containerPort` automatically. I am able to prepend it using

```yaml
- name: Creating custom ports
  set_fact:
    container_ports: "{{ ports | map('regex_replace', '(^)', '- containerPort: \\1') | list }}"
  when: ports is defined
```

This does only create

```
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "container_ports": [
            "- containerPort: 123",
            "- containerPort: 456",
            "- containerPort: 789"
        ]
    }
```

though, which is close, but not quite right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this like so:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ports:
      - 123
      - 456

  tasks:
    - name: Creating custom ports
      set_fact:
        container_ports: '{{ ports | map("regex_replace", "^(.*)$", "containerPort: \1") | map("from_yaml") | list }}'
    - debug:
        var: container_ports
...
```

The trick is to convert each item into a YAML hash and then convert that to a Python dict using `from_yaml`.

Debug output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "container_ports": [
        {
            "containerPort": 123
        }, 
        {
            "containerPort": 456
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An other solution using `json_query`

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    ports:
      - 123
      - 456

  tasks:
    - name: Tranform raw list to Kubernetes compatible format
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ports | json_query('[].{\"containerPort\": @}') }}"
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Tranform raw list to Kubernetes compatible format] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "containerPort": 123
        },
        {
            "containerPort": 456
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I tried to add a second field by using `service_ports: "{{ ports | json_query('[].{\"name\": \"portname\", \"port\": @}') }}"` - however this results in `portname` simply beeing null. How can I set a string there?